# All Errorpages customize at WebView

Tags: android, redirect, webview, custom-error-pages

I have some troubles with my WebView app.
I want for all possible error-pages (e.g connection lost, server timeout etc.) a customized errorpage which is offline available in the app.

So that means that there is a redirect to the offline-page in the webview if anything goes wrong.
I don't wanna make a different between TimeOut or Internet connection is lost I just wanna one redirect for all possible web-errors to the offline site.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wanna one redirect for all possible web-errors to the offline site.

I think you need a custom `WebView` class for URL redirection if any error occurs.

`MainActivity.java`

```
/* ... */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<!-- ... -->
<your_package_name.MyWebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<!-- ... -->
```

`MyWebView.java`

```
/* ... */
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void initView(Context context){

        this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) ;
        this.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        this.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        this.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        this.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

              @Override
              public void onReceivedError(final WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                          final String failingUrl) {

                      MyWebView.this.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

              }

              @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
              @Override
              public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError errorResponse) {

                      MyWebView.this.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
              }
          });

    }

}
```

Remember put your `error.html` inside `app/src/main/assets`

Comment: You can just replace the `error.html` to your offline site, it worked for online (has Internet) and offline (no Internet). Both states can open `error.html` successfully

Comment: I've forgtotten to set permissions to use the Internet connection. ;)